# nasm: error: more than one input file specified

Tags: assembly

Estou tentando compilar um arquivo nasm mas ele está retornando o seguinte erro:
" nasm: error: more than one input file specified ". Qual o erro? 
boot.asm:

```
BITS 16 ; The mode we are running in (default for every modern computer)
ORG 0x7c00 ; the origin, the boot loader is always loaded at 7C00 by the BIOS
jmp Main ; Jump the a label called "Main"


;IN: si=string, OUT:-
Print:
lodsb ; Load string byte (Load a character that's in si into al)
cmp al, 0 ; If that character is equal to "0" jump to done
je Done

mov ah, 0eh ; Set parameters for interrupt 10
int 10h ; Call the interrupt
jmp Print ; Loop back in Print to print the next character

Done: 
ret ; return back to the place we where called

Main:
mov si, msg ; Move the data of msg into si
call Print ; Call the Print label
cli 
hlt ; Halt the system

msg db 'Hello World!',0 ; Define the variable msg to a string

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; make sure the file is 512 bytes

dw 0xAA55 ; Last 2 bytes need to be AA55
```

Eu estou usando o seguinte comando para compilar:

```
nasm -f boot.asm -a boot.bin
```

Comment: Como está o `makefile`? qual a sintaxe você usa para compilar?

Comment: Ainda não criei o makefile, creio que não será preciso. Usei a seguinte sintaxe: nasm -f boot.asm -a boot.bin

Comment: A sintaxe está errada, o `-f` indica qual formato você quer usar, por exemplo `bin` (para ver os formatos válidos digite: `nasm -hf`).

Comment: Poderia me passar a sintaxe completa?

Comment: Tente assim: `nasm boot.asm -o boot.bin -f bin`.

Comment: Funcionou! Comente para eu dar reputação e resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe que é usada para compilar está incorreta, a opção `-f` é usada para especificar o formato de saída do arquivo, enquanto a opção `-a` é usada para suprimir o *pré-processamento* e assumir que o compilador já fez isso, neste caso essa opção também não é necessária.

Para compilar para binário você pode fazer (*binário* é o formato **padrão**):

```
nasm boot.asm -o boot.bin
```

Para saber quais os formatos disponíveis use a opção `-hf`.

Mais informações: [**Chapter 2: Running NASM**](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~comp03/nasm/nasmdoc2.html)